# SNMP: get list of interfaces with corresponding IPs

Tags: snmp, cisco

I have a list of IP addresses or Cisco router. Now i need to find out, which IP address is assigned to which interface (e.g. i have IP 192.168.1.1 and i need to learn that it is IP address of fa0/0 interface). Which MIB can i use to get the list of IP add with corresponding interfaces via SNMP?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I believe the SNMP OID you need for this is 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.34, the object being ipAddressTable from the IP-MIB. See the following URL:

http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=Translate&objectInput=1.3.6.1.2.1.4.34#oidContent

Cisco has very good SNMP info on their site. The SNMP Object Navigator, or the IOS MIB Locator are your friends. Tons of info there, and you can look at it from any angle you want. For example, provide the router's IOS image filename and see what MIBs it supports, etc.

As far as interfaces and IP address info, that's the most basic of stuff so you will be ok, no need to find any weird MIB for that.

My suggestion would be: make sure SNMP is enabled on the router and an SNMP community is set, jump on a Unix/Linux box and point `snmpwalk` to it and pull all available info. That, paired with the MIB file, is usually the best way to make sure which element you want. If on Windows, there are several free SNMP clients that can "snmpwalk" a device and do the equivalent.

Let me know how that goes!

Answer (score 1):

You can try the OID 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20 to get the list of IP add with corresponding interfaces via SNMP.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, i had a list of IPs before, i needed just to match them with int names. I did it using 2 MIBs - 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.20.1.2.+IPaddress returns the index of interface and using this index i used 1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2.+IntfIndex (obtained in previous step). I did it for every IP address in list and works like charm.

Answer (score -1):

There is also the ifxTable which has improved interface speed information for high speed ethernet ports:

http://tools.cisco.com/Support/SNMP/do/BrowseOID.do?local=en&translate=true&objectInput=ifXTable